# Find employees latest activity is slow when adding ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am working on a legacy system in Laravel and I am trying to pull the latest action of some specific types of actions an `employee` has done.

Performance is good when I don't add `ORDER BY`. When adding it the query will go from something like 130 ms to 18 seconds. There are about 1.5 million rows in the `actions` table. There are 2.5 million rows in the `pivot` table.

How do I fix the performance problem?

I have tried to isolate the problem by cutting out all the other parts of the query so it is more readable for you:

```
SELECT
    employees.id,
    (
        SELECT actions.date)
        FROM pivot
        JOIN actions
        ON pivot.actions_id = actions.id
        WHERE employees.id = pivot.employee_id
        AND actions.type = 'meeting'
        LIMIT 1
        ORDER BY actions.id DESC
    ) AS latest_action
FROM employees
ORDER BY latest_action DESC
```

I tried using `LEFT JOIN` and `MAX()` instead but it didn't seem to solve my problem.

I just added a subquery because it was the original query is already very complex. But if you have an alternative suggestion I am all ears.

Result of `EXPLAIN`:

```
id  select_type         table       partitions  type    possible_keys                       key                 key_len ref                     rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY             employees   NULL        ALL     NULL                                NULL                NULL    NULL                    15217   10          Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  pivot       NULL        ref     actions_type_index,pivot_type_index pivot_type_index    4       dev.employees.id        104     11.11       Using index condition
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  actions     NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY,Logs                        PRIMARY             4       dev.pivot.actions_id    1       6.68        Using where
```

Here is the indexes. The index `employee_type` I don't think is important for my specific query, but maybe it should be re-worked?

```
# pivot table
KEY `actions_type_index` (`actions_id`,`employee_type`),
KEY `pivot_type_index` (`employee_id`,`employee_type`)

# actions table
KEY `Logs` (`type`,`id`,`is_log`)
# I tried to add `date` index to `actions` table but the problem remains.
KEY `date_index` (`date`)
```

**UPDATE**

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE `pivot` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actions_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `employee_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `actions_type_index` (`actions_id`,`employee_type`),
  KEY `employee_type_index` (`employee_id`,`employee_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2960893 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `actions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_log` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `data` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_group` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `endDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Logs` (`type`,`id`,`is_log`),
  KEY `date_index` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1368630 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `employees_id_unique` (`id`),
  KEY `employees_created_by_user_index` (`created_by_user`),
  KEY `employees_updated_by_user_index` (`updated_by_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22012 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` for all of the tables in the query!

Comment: @Vérace: I have updated my question with information from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

Comment: @Akina: I have the same problem even if I only use `AND actions.type = 'meeting'`. Also the problem remains without `DATE_FORMAT()`. I have changed the question so it doesn't muddy the waters so to speak.

Comment: @Akina: I actually forgot to add that to the question, I used i little bit different version of what I am testing. I have updated the question.

Comment: Does greater `actions.id` means greater `actions.date` strongly? And specify your server version.

Comment: Yes, greater ID means greater date. I am using MySQL 5.7 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT employees.id, MAX(actions.date) AS latest_action
FROM employees, pivot, actions
WHERE employees.id = pivot.employee_id
  AND pivot.actions_id = actions.id
  AND actions.type = 'meeting'
GROUP BY employees.id
ORDER BY latest_action DESC
```

Create index `pivot(employee_id, actions_id)`.

Create index `actions(type,id,date)` (or maybe `actions(id,type,date)` - test).